# upgrading mongodb cluster. Is there a table for mongos (MongoDB Shard Utility) compatibility?

Tags: mongodb

I need to upgrade mongodb cluster
There are many applications accessing mongodb using mongos (MongoDB Shard Utility)

I need to know which versions are compatible
In other words,  can I install mongos 6.0 ,  and it will connect to mongodb 3.6 ?

I tried searching but couldn't find any documentation
I only found documentation regarding drivers versions to mongodb versions

Comment: it's not recommended to upgrade a server on more than one version at once. Mongos is a part of server binaries so I think it should follow to the same pattern. Also I would not recommend using mongos from one server version ship but server binaries from different

Comment: You have to upgrade step by step for each major release. Follow the upgrade procedure in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0-upgrade-sharded-cluster/)

Comment: Even if you don't set the `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` it should fail. Range of `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` in [MongoDB version 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) is `4.2` to `6.0`, so version 3.6 will not work, I assume.